# Confusion of pipe syntax in AWK

Tags: shell, awk, pipe

The example code is like this, it does the statistic of number of times the first column appears and sort the result.

```
    { dist[$1]+=1; }
END { for (i in dist) {
        print i,dist[i] | "sort"
      }
    }
```

In my opinion, the process is like this:

**(WORKFLOW A)**

1) print all element in the `dist`, save them all to a buffer

2) get all elements in the buffer, and pipe them to `sort` function

But in the example above, the process looks like this:

**(WORKFLOW B)**

1) print one element in the `dist`, and then pipe it to `sort` function

2) process the next element in the `dist`, until no new element in `dist`

I was wondering why I shouldn't place the `sort` like this:

```
    { dist[$1]+=1; }
END { for (i in dist) {
        print i,dist[i] 
      } 
      | "sort"
    }
```

Anyone has any idea about the reason? And how can I write the `pipe` if I want to do the work like `WORKFLOW B`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't do it the second way is because `| "command"` is part of the syntax of awk's `print` command, it can't be used with arbitrary statements or statement groups. The same thing goes for `> filename`.

The way it works is that the first time it encounters a redirection to a file or pipe, it opens that file/pipe, and keeps that descriptor open. Then every time you redirect to the same file/pipe, it sends the output to the corresponding descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

See @barmar's answer for "why not", and here's how to get that functionality (invoke sort at the end of the loop) to address the second part of your question:

```
    { dist[$1]+=1; }
END { for (i in dist) {
        out = out i OFS dist[i] ORS 
      } 
      printf "%s",out | "sort"
    }
```